# Need to add 3px of padding to an empty div... I cannot access the markup, only the css

Tags: css

I'm tasked with making a change to a website which I'm not sure is even possible.

We have one element which is an image surrounded by 3px padding, a 1px border, and then a drop shadow.

[image: This is the one that works correctly]

The above image is how the y would like it

[image: These ones they want changed]

This one does not look as they want it.

We have another element which is an empty div with a background color set. The designer wants these two to look the same, but I only have access to the CSS. Is there some way I can get this to look the same using pseudo selectors?

Here's the CSS:

```
    float: left;
    height: 23px;
    margin: 3px;
    width: 23px;
    padding:2px;
    border:1px solid #d4d4d4;
    box-shadow:3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
     -moz-box-shadow:3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
     -webkit-box-shadow:3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
```

Comment: I am trying to understand the issue better. You basically want to style the empty `<div>` to exactly look the way the designer wanted? You can try to target the empty `<div>` based on the DOM structure.

Comment: I can edit the class on the empty div. The problem is when you add padding, it only makes the div bigger. There is no way that I know of to add a white ring inside the border when the background is set short of adding a parent element, which I cannot do. I mean... I suppose I could with javascript but that is not worth the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the `:before` or `:after` pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content) to create an extra "hook" that will allow you to add two borders to your div. Like this:

```
div:before {
  background: blue;
  border: 3px solid white;
  /* :before will only display if it generates content,
     but that content may be empty: */
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
}

div {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

This essentially works as if your empty div looked like this instead:

```
<div><div:before> </div:before></div>
```

If it's just a matter of having multiple borders or shadows, though, I'd go with [Doug's far simpler answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262874/need-to-add-3px-of-padding-to-an-empty-div-i-cannot-access-the-markup-only-th/7367806#7367806).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `outline` property, which draws outside the `border`.

[Example](http://cssdesk.com/tStLr)

```
background:lightblue;
height: 23px;
margin: 3px;
width: 23px;
padding:2px;
border:3px solid white;
outline:1px solid #d4d4d4;
```

**Edit:** The outline will cover your drop shadow, so add a spread value to your `box-shadow` properties:

```
box-shadow:3px 3px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-moz-box-shadow:3px 3px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-webkit-box-shadow:3px 3px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
```

Comment: The `outline` will overlap the `box-shadow`, though, so you're only left with a 3 pixel shadow. You can overcome that by adding a spread radius to the shadow: `box-shadow:3px 3px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)`.

Comment: Nice... it's not every day I get to learn a new CSS property. I'm going to start using this a lot because it appears to be outside of the box-model, which is how I've always felt border should work.

Comment: Interestingly, the outline renders outside of the box shadow in FF6 for Mac, so I guess I can't use this after all.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this method -

### CSS

```
div {
    float: left;
    background: #abcdef;
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    border:1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

div:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 8px;
    content: "";
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    box-shadow:3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
     -moz-box-shadow:3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
     -webkit-box-shadow:3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

### Example

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/4TLEQ/)

### Reference

A great [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-multiple-borders-with-simple-css/) for a technique of this sort

Comment: This seems overly complicated and only actually works by accident in the fiddle. Absolutely positioning the `:after` element means it will be stuck to the top of the page. You'd need to add `position: relative` to the `div`, at least, but then the `top` and `left` offsets need to be changed too.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming CSS3 could be applied here, try using the new [`box-sizing` property](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-sizing/).

Answer (score 1):

Dude, I totally figured out another method that is way better than the others, including the one I gave before. (I got the idea [here](http://blog.w3conversions.com/2011/09/css3-spread-value-and-box-shadow-on-one-side-only/#attachment_941), and it makes me feel dumb I didn't think of this before.)

You can use multiple box-shadows, like so:

```
.multipleBordersPlusADropShadowAsWell
{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff, 
                0 0 0 4px #555, 
                3px 3px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/guitarzan/F3ESq/)

The box shadows overlay each other with the first ones on top. The first two have zero blur and finite spread so they act like borders. The third has a blur plus spread to show up outside the first two.

Answer (score 0):

Use a bigger border:     `border:4px solid #ffffff;`

Comment: There is already a border of 1px solid #d4d4d4. They want three white pixels between the block of color and the border.

Comment: Ok, use a 3-pixel border. This will make it look like padding. Nothing else is going to work without nesting another element.